# std::lower_bound on a set with its reverse order

Tags: c++, set

Say I have a `std::set<int>` and I want to perform `lower_bound(x)` operations in both ways. That is,

- get the first element greater than or equal to `x`
- get the last element less than or equal to `x`

With `std::vector`, I could do this using **one** sorted `vector`

```
std::vector<int> v({1,2,3, 5,6});
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
auto a = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 4); // gives 5
auto b = std::lower_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 4, greater<int>()); // gives 3
```

Can I do something similar with `std::set`, or do I have to maintain an additional `set` with the same values but with a reversed comparator?

Comment: Aside: you don't need to `sort` your vector here, it's already in the right order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on rustyx's answer, here is a bit more elegant implementation:

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
typename set<T>::reverse_iterator rlower_bound(set<T>& s, const T x) {
   if(s.empty()) return s.rend();
   auto it = s.upper_bound(x);
   return make_reverse_iterator(it);
}

template<typename T>
typename set<T>::reverse_iterator rupper_bound(set<T>& s, const T x) {
   if(s.empty()) return s.rend();
   auto it = s.lower_bound(x);
   return make_reverse_iterator(it);
}

int main() {
   set<int> s({1,2,3, 5,6});
   int x = 4;
   cout << *s.lower_bound(x) << endl;
   cout << *rlower_bound(s, x) << endl;
}
```

Also, this is consistent with my vector example where you get a`reverse_iterator` when performing the reverse `lower_bound`

Answer (score 1):

> Can I do something similar with `std::set`

Yes, `std::set<int>` is always in `std::less<int>` order, and it's reverse iterators are in `std::greater<int>` order.

```
std::set<int> v({1,2,3, 5,6});
auto a = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 4); // 5
auto b = std::lower_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 4, std::greater<int>()); // 3
```

If your set had a custom comparator, you could do something similar with

```
template<typename Compare>
class reverse_compare {
    Compare comp;
    bool operator()(auto lhs, auto rhs) {
        return comp(rhs, lhs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require creating an additional `set`, one for each order?  My question is whether it's possible to query both operations on one `set`.

Comment: @3mar if you replace `vector` with `set` in your example, and remove the `sort`, everything remains fine.

Comment: have you tired it? it gives a punch of compile errors on my machine.

Comment: @3mar oops, was iterators not values. you are missing `std::` from greater in the question btw

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` contains unique values, so to get "*the last element less than `x`*" one can just use [`set::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/lower_bound) to get an iterator to the first element `>= x` and then decrement it. Then with a simple if-check the solution can be extended to support values `<= x`.

Something like this:

```
int main() {
    std::set<int> v({ 1,2,3, 5,6 });
    int x = 4;
    auto a = v.lower_bound(x);
    if (a == v.end()) return 1; // handle the not-found case ...
    auto b = a;  // b "points" to the element >= x
    if (*a != x) {
        a--; // a now "points" to the element <= x
        if (a == v.end()) return 1; // handle the not-found case ...
    }
    std::cout << *a << ", " << *b << "\n"; // prints 3, 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the check on `a` be like 
`if(a == v.begin()) return 1;
else a--`?

Comment: No, `v.end()` is a special "out-of-bounds" iterator. `a == v.end()` is a check against an "out-of-bounds"/"not found" condition.

Comment: The same can be said for the `vector` case